# How Hilbert space helps to know distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I was reading S Kesavan Topics in Functional analysis

In that Auther says that

Let $f\in L^2(R)$  D is space of infinite differentiable function with compact support in R
Since $L^2(R)$ is Hilbert space, f completely known once its inner product with each element $D(\Sigma)$ known i.e when all then numbers $\int f\phi$, $\phi\in D$ are known.

I do not understand the above abstract. I know that D are dense in $L^2(R)$
But How it helps to know f completely I do not know.

Any Help Hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an accepted answer already but I'm not sure it's what the author meant. For $f_1,f_2\in H$, a Hilbert space with inner product $(\;,\;)$, if $(f_1,g)=(f_2,g)$ for all $g$ in a dense subset of $H$, then $f_1=f_2$. To see that, take $g$ approximating $f_1-f_2$.

Comment: I had one doubt is this not true for any space or there must be Hilbert space. Can you please refer me some theorem

Comment: Theorem: For $f_1,f_2\in H$, a Hilbert space with inner product $(\;,\;)$, if $(f_1,g)=(f_2,g)$ for all $g$ in a dense subset $D$ of $H$, then $f_1=f_2$. Proof: by density there are $g_n$ in $D$ with $g_n\to h:=f_1-f_2$ as $n\to\infty$. The inner product is continuous in each variable, so $(h,g_n)\to (h,h)$ as $n\to\infty$. But $(h,g_n)=(f_1,g_n)-(f_2,g_n)=0$ by hypothesis. So $\|h\|^2=(h,h)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$, so $\|h\|=0$, so $f_1-f_2=h=0$, so $f_1=f_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the author here is talking about the approximation to the identity using [a mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier). That is: if $\varphi $ is a mollifier then $\{\varphi_\epsilon: \epsilon >0\} \subset D$ and we have that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}f*\varphi _\epsilon (x)=f(x)
$$
for any chosen $f\in L^p$ for $p\in[1,\infty )$. In particular when $p=2$ then $f*\varphi (x)=\langle f,\overline{\varphi (x-\cdot )} \rangle$, so the inner product can be used to approximate the values of $f$ in neighborhoods of any point. This is the whole point of the theory of distributions.